# SQL command in pgsql via PQexec fails for special characters like m³ or µ

Tags: c++, postgresql

```
void UpdateRecords(PGconn *conn, std::string &records)
{
    if(!records.empty())
    {
         std::string sql;
         sql.append("INSERT INTO data.record VALUES ");
         sql.append(records);

         PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, sql.c_str());
    }
}
```

Here records has data separated by comma for each column. If any special character is available in sql string, like `µ` or `m³` record is not updated in database (query fails).

Error message `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb5`
Database Version `9.6.12`
Database encoding: `UTF8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is expecting you to send utf8, but you are sending something else. Probably LATIN1-extended.

You can fix this by first doing a `set client_encoding to latin1` on your connection, so the database knows what encoding you are sending to it.

You could also change `records` so that they actually do contain UTF8 characters, but that seems harder.  Or at least, I don't know to make C++ do that off the top of my head.

Comment: How do I know what encoding data I'm sending?

Comment: I don't know.  0xb5 is mu in LATIN1 and you specifically mentioned mu, so that is my guess.  You should know the source of your data and what encoding it uses, but if you don't then guessing is the best you can do.

Comment: Current encoding for connection can be determined by `PQclientEncoding` and that is also same as database encoding UTF8.

Comment: PQclientEncoding tells you back what you told the database (or allowed as the default).  But you told it the wrong thing, in that it doesn't match the actual data you are trying to send.  The question is, what is the actual encoding of the data?